# TCPDF email error

Tags: php, email, pdf

I use TCPDF to send pdf as an attachment. I do receive the email, so the email works, but there is no attachment.

In the email I receive a very long scrambled message. If I remove `$data` (as in code below) the content of the message is much less, but still no attachment.

```
<?php
//This file create a pd contract agreement based on the client's detail. 
// Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');
require_once('connect.php');


//Connect and get information

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);




$findaccount = $conn->prepare("SELECT * from Table'");


$findaccount->execute();

//Variable list here and working



// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Me');
$pdf->SetTitle('My Title');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' ', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

 // ---------------------------------------------------------

/*
 NOTES:
 - To create self-signed signature: openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365000       -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout tcpdf.crt -out tcpdf.crt
- To export crt to p12: openssl pkcs12 -export -in tcpdf.crt -out tcpdf.p12
 - To convert pfx certificate to pem: openssl pkcs12 -in tcpdf.pfx -out tcpdf.crt -nodes
 */

// set certificate file
$certificate = 'file://data/cert/tcpdf.crt';

// set additional information
$info = array(
'Name' => 'My Site',
'Location' => 'Address',
'Reason' => 'Because',
'ContactInfo' => 'https://www.example.com',
);

// set document signature
$pdf->setSignature($certificate, $certificate, 'tcpdfdemo', '', 2,    $info);

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 7);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// print a line of text
$text = "<html><head></head><body>
<b>HTML DISPLAY HERE</b>
<br>
<br>

</body></html>
";

$pdf->writeHTML($text, true, 0, true, 0);

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
// *** set signature appearance ***

// create content for signature (image and/or text)

// define active area for signature appearance
$pdf->setSignatureAppearance(180, 60, 15, 15);

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

// *** set an empty signature appearance ***
$pdf->addEmptySignatureAppearance(180, 80, 15, 15);

// ---------------------------------------------------------

//Close and output PDF document
$fileatt = $pdf->Output('file_name.pdf', 'E');

//define the receiver of the email
$name = "Name";
$email = "email@email.com";

$to = "email@email.com";

$from = "From Name ";

$subject = "Subject text";


//$fileatt = "./test.pdf";

$fileatttype = "application/pdf";

$fileattname = "newname.pdf";

$headers = "From: $from";

$file = fopen($fileatt, 'rb');



fclose($file);

$semi_rand = md5(time());

$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
" boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
"-{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
$message .= "\n\n";

$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

$message .= "–{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type: {$fileatttype};\n" .
" name=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" .
"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
" filename=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
$data . "\n\n" .
"-{$mime_boundary}-\n";

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
echo "The email was sent.";
} else {
echo "There was an error sending the mail.";
}
//============================================================+
// END OF FILE
//============================================================+
```

**Update**

I made some changed and can now receive an attachment, but the attachment doesnt open due to error

[image]

and there is no content in the email apart from the attachment.

```
// Settings
$name        = "Name goes here";
$email       = "email@gmail.com";
$to          = "$name <$email>";
$from        = "From";
$subject     = "Subject";
$mainMessage = "Hi, here's the file.";
$fileatt     = "mypdf.pdf"; //file location
$fileatttype = "application/pdf";
$fileattname = "mypdf.pdf"; //name that you want to use to send or you can use the same name
$headers = "From: $from";

// File
$file = fopen($fileatt, 'rb');
$data = fread($file, filesize($fileatt));
fclose($file);

// This attaches the file
$semi_rand     = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
$headers      .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
" boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
"-{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
$mainMessage  . "\n\n";

$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type: {$fileatttype};\n" .
" name=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" .
"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
" filename=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
$data . "\n\n" .
"-{$mime_boundary}-\n";

// Send the email
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {

echo "The email was sent.";

}
else {

echo "There was an error sending the mail.";
}
```

Comment: you should not call $pdf->Output twice, $fileatt is a string not a file, its already base64 encoded

Comment: @nogad Thanks. What a rookie mistake. I changed it in my code (removed the first one). Still not working

Comment: you are still trying to open as string as a file and encode it even though it is already encoded

Comment: @nogad I am not following? What should I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem.

```
//define the receiver of the email
$to = 'email@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Subject';
$repEmail = 'me@email.com  ';

$fileName = 'output.pdf';
$fileatt = $pdf->Output($fileName, 'E');
$attachment = chunk_split($fileatt);
$eol = PHP_EOL;
$separator = md5(time());

$headers = 'From: From <'.$repEmail.'>'.$eol;
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' .$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";

$message = "--".$separator.$eol;
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;
$message .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol;

$message .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;

$message .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$message .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$fileName."\"".$eol; 
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$message .= $attachment.$eol;
$message .= "--".$separator."--";


// Send the email
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {

echo "The email was sent.";

}
else {

echo "There was an error sending the mail.";
}
```